# Virtual subclass does not require to implement abstract methods?

Tags: python

I have base class with 2 abstract methods load and save

```
import abc
class PluginBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def load(self, input):
        """Retrieve data from the input source and return an object."""
        return

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def save(self, output, data):
        """Save the data object to the output."""
        return
```

Below class is virtual subclass of RegisteredImplementation

```
class RegisteredImplementation(object):
    pass

PluginBase.register(RegisteredImplementation)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Subclass:', issubclass(RegisteredImplementation, PluginBase)
    print 'Instance:', isinstance(RegisteredImplementation(), PluginBase)

    
    True
    True
```

I was expecting Error "Can't Initialize abstract class

What is use virtual subclass?

Comment: The use of a virtual subclass is to enable classification by "duck typing". Example, to be an `Iterable` and satisfy `isinstance(obj, Iterable)`, all you must do is implement the `__iter__` method, but you don't have to explicitly set a parent class with abstract method. If you want this class to be non-instantiable without the methods, then use a concreate implementation of the abstract class `class RegisteredImplementation(PluginBase):`, and not use a virtual subclass.